# Cannot use GraphQLObjectType \"Query\" from another module or realm

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am using `apollo-server-express` to build graphql server

My resolvers in `server.js` is as simple as that

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { importSchema } = require('graphql-import');
const typeDefs = importSchema('./src/schema.graphql');
const prisma = require('./src/prisma');

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
       users(parent, args, { prisma }, info) {
        return prisma.query.users(args, info);
      }
    }
  },
  context: ({ req }) => ({ ...req, prisma })
});

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () =>
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`)
);
```

and i am getting this error when i run users query

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot use GraphQLObjectType \"Query\" from another module or realm.\n\nEnsure that there is only one instance of \"graphql\" in the node_modules\ndirectory. If different versions of \"graphql\" are the dependencies of other\nrelied on modules, use \"resolutions\" to ensure only one version is installed.\n\nhttps://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions\n\nDuplicate \"graphql\" modules cannot be used at the same time since different\nversions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one\nversion used in the function from another could produce confusing and\nspurious results.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "users"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "Error: Cannot use GraphQLObjectType \"Query\" from another module or realm.",
            "",
            "Ensure that there is only one instance of \"graphql\" in the node_modules",
            "directory. If different versions of \"graphql\" are the dependencies of other",
            "relied on modules, use \"resolutions\" to ensure only one version is installed.",
            "",
            "https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions",
            "",
            "Duplicate \"graphql\" modules cannot be used at the same time since different",
            "versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one",
            "version used in the function from another could produce confusing and",
            "spurious results.",
            "    at instanceOf (D:\\00. DEVELOPMENT\\FULL PROJECTS\\social-template-2\\node_modules\\graphql-binding\\node_modules\\graphql\\jsutils\\instanceOf.js:28:13)",
            "    at isObjectType (D:\\00. DEVELOPMENT\\FULL PROJECTS\\social-template-2\\node_modules\\graphql-binding\\node_modules\\graphql\\type\\definition.js:116:34)",
            "    at TypeInfo.enter (D:\\00. DEVELOPMENT\\FULL PROJECTS\\social-template-2\\node_modules\\graphql-binding\\node_modules\\graphql\\utilities\\TypeInfo.js:163:61)",
            "    at Object.enter (D:\\00. DEVELOPMENT\\FULL PROJECTS\\social-template-2\\node_modules\\graphql-binding\\node_modules\\graphql\\language\\visitor.js:369:16)",
            "    at Object.visit (D:\\00. DEVELOPMENT\\FULL PROJECTS\\social-template-2\\node_modules\\graphql-binding\\node_modules\\graphql\\language\\visitor.js:242:26)",
            "    at replaceFieldsWithFragments (D:\\00. DEVELOPMENT\\FULL PROJECTS\\social-template-2\\node_modules\\graphql-binding\\node_modules\\graphql-tools\\src\\transforms\\ReplaceFieldWithFragment.ts:67:10)",
            "    at ReplaceFieldWithFragment.transformRequest (D:\\00. DEVELOPMENT\\FULL PROJECTS\\social-template-2\\node_modules\\graphql-binding\\node_modules\\graphql-tools\\src\\transforms\\ReplaceFieldWithFragment.ts:45:22)",
            "    at D:\\00. DEVELOPMENT\\FULL PROJECTS\\social-template-2\\node_modules\\graphql-binding\\node_modules\\graphql-tools\\src\\transforms\\transforms.ts:24:21",
            "    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)",
            "    at Object.applyRequestTransforms (D:\\00. DEVELOPMENT\\FULL PROJECTS\\social-template-2\\node_modules\\graphql-binding\\node_modules\\graphql-tools\\src\\transforms\\transforms.ts:21:21)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

and here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "social-template-2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon --ext js,graphql --exec babel-node server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.17.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "graphql-import": "^1.0.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "prisma-binding": "^2.3.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prisma/cli": "^2.7.1",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea what could be wrong here ?

Comment: Looks like a `graphql` package version mismatch. Could you try using an eariler version like _14_ for this and check?

Comment: @Ryan just did that, installed graphql@14.0.0 => same error!

Comment: then i found it needs peer for 14.2.1. then i installed it. now i have graphql@14.2.1 and still have the same issue, and i delete package-lock every time and npm i again. But still same error!

Comment: what's the output of `yarn why graphql`?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably another graphql in your node_modules.
try to check it with:

```
find node_modules -name graphql
```

then look in package.json of each graphql modules and check what version is there.

Finally, what helped in my case is just uninstalling all packages that contain graphql and install them again together:

```
npm uninstall apollo-server apollo-server-express graphql neo4j-driver neo4j-graphql-js

npm install apollo-server apollo-server-express graphql neo4j-driver neo4j-graphql-js --force
```